# Problems with echoing array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I am having trouble echoing values from an array. I am using a mysql query to create an array, `$online`, containing the names of currently online users. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $goodbye = time() - 300;
    $qry="SELECT UserName FROM Members WHERE Seen >=$goodbye";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    if($result) {
        $online = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        foreach($online as $u) {
            echo $u;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        die("Query Failed");
    }
?>
```

When viewing this on my web page, only the first index of the array is shown (as in: if User1, User17, and User69 are all online, only User1 will appear on the list). I'm sure this is happening because I'm using echo incorrectly, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: `mysql_query` and its related family of functions are **ancient** and you should no longer be using them. They have been deprecated, and will shortly be removed from the language. Please find a tutorial on PHP Data Objects.

Comment: @meagar Yes, I am aware of that. That's not my problem here, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop it like ([mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php))

```
if($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["UserName"];
    }
}
```

Also, notice the `Warning`.

Comment: Also, I am aware of the warning. I'm currently working on going through my site and updating all of that.